# Program for opening .csv files with custom delimiter

Tags: gratis, csv

I am looking for a program that can open and display nicely .csv files and gives you the ability to set the delimiter of each file.That's because most of the files I handle have some weird delimiters like £ or $.

I've been usind [CsvEd](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl)  for quite a long time but I was wondering if there are other "players" too.

OS requirements: Windows Vista/7 or Linux (especially Mint)

Comment: Should the program also be able to save the files after editing?

Comment: not mandatory but sure, why not. My main problem is the viewing of the csv because most editors do not support custom delimiters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [OpenOffice](https://www.openoffice.org/) (or [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/), which is pretty much the same):

- free and open source
- Windows and Linux
- specify the delimiter when importing the CSV:

[image]

Comment: I guess I forgotten about the office family. That was because most .csv files are usually dumps from a procedure and are too big and fatty to be opened by those programs, but still this answer covers everything in my question. Accepting because I generally use OpenOffice and worked fine with a small csv I have :)

Comment: For large CSV files I often dump them into a DB, or use 010 Editor but the latter does not display CSV nicely :/

Answer (score 6):

For Windows, if you have Microsoft Office, you can use Excel. You have the ability to set a custom delimiter when importing text files:

[image: Excel custom delimiter]

Comment: MS Office isn't gratis. There is a gratis trial of 30 days, though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/) (free, web-based). Create a new spreadsheet, go to File > import, then specify the delimiter:

[image]